# How to fix cvxpy output of arrays?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I am trying to write a portfolio optimization problem using cvxpy.

```
initial_weights = [0.045, 0.035, 0.024, 0.028...]
rets = (np.log(data/data.shift(1))
w = cvx.Variable(38)
ret = np.sum(rets.mean()*w)*252
prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(ret), [cvx.sum_entries(w)==1, w>0.02, w<0.06])
```

result = prob.solve()
After solving, w.value is of the form [[0.02], [0.02], [0.04]...]

I need to add more constraints like abs(list_final_weights-w)>0.005, but that will be possible if w.value is of the form of array of values instead of array of arrays. How can I fix this error?

Comment: What's `x` in the constraint?

Comment: That was an error. x is the variable w.

Answer (score 0):

`cvxpy` does element-wise operations for subtraction, as long as they're of the same shape. You could convert your flat array into the appropriate shape that the solver needs - In this case it's (N, 1) instead of a flat array of shape (N,).

```
list_final_weights = np.reshape(list_final_weights, [len(list_final_weights), 1])
```

Then you should be able to do the subtraction for the constraint:

```
list_final_weights - w >= 0.005
```

Also `cvxpy` does not allow hard `>` or `<` inequalities. Only `<=` and `>=`.
https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#constraints

Comment: I need the absolute difference to be >=0.005 but when I do abs(list_final_weights-w)>0.005, I get a bad operand error. Is there any other way to write this?

Comment: use `np.abs` instead of the inbuilt `abs`. The inbuilt one cannot handle arrays.

Comment: np.abs gives the same type error: bad operand type for Add Expression

Comment: Can you share the line of code that raised the error?

Comment: const = [cvx.sum_entries(w)==1, w>=0.02, w<=0.06, np.abs(w-list_final_weights)>=0.005]

Comment: The issue is not with `np.abs`. It's with the first constraint. Try doing `cvx.sum(w)==1` or `np.sum(w)==1` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Still the same error. TypeError: Bad operand type for abs(): 'AddExpression'

Comment: Last ditch effort - use `cvxopt.abs` instead of `np.abs`. Even if that doesn't work, I am not sure what else can be done here except contacting the developers of the library.